# Relay with built in manual switch

Tags: switches, relay

I have a question regarding the manual type relay switch shown in the picture.

I need relay with dual coil-latching, I thought of using avmomentary toggle SPDT to turn the relay on and off, but I will not know the position of the lever of the switch (whether it is set or reset.) If I use a relay with a built in manual switch which is on the top of the relay, is it possible to set and reset the relay using that without needing any external momentary switches? If I use the normal one then I would need an additional digital latch or flipflop.

Please let me know if I can the manual switch type relay and also let me know if there are any disadvantages with the manual type relay switch.

FYI: Relay -  ADJH23112
[image]

Comment: You haven’t provided very much information about your application. Not convinced you couldn’t replace the relay with a light switch.

Answer (score 1):

The manual lever, which serves as a test button to carry out checks during installation, is not intended for normal use. It will neither set nor reset the relay.

I suppose a toggle switch or an MCB would be a better choice for your application.

> But if I use the SPDT momentary toggle switch to set or reset then I would not be able to know which state it was triggered last. Do you have any simple circuit suggestion for this? Like any kind of indicator which says it was in set or reset position?

An indicator lamp 'H1' in the load circuit would do.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if I use the SPDT momentary toggle switch to set or reset then I would not be able to know which state it was triggered last. Do you have any  simple circuit suggestion for this? Like any kind of indicator which says it was in set or reset position.?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that there are manual switches that can also be electrically actuated via a solenoid.

Comment: @Hearth, Many thanks for the information.

Comment: @vu2nan, are you sure that the manual lever wont set or reset the relay? I am confirming this because, few answered me that it is like a normal switch where we can set or reset. I just want to make sure

Comment: @vu2nan, But the load is switching at 400V AC and 40A rms so I dont think lamp would do the job

Comment: Hi Manjesh, The contact rating is 50 A (resistive) @ AC 277 V.  Max. switching voltage AC 480 V and max. switching current AC 50A  cannot be applied together. The relay contact can be opened or closed by the lever with the coils de-energised. An on/off switch / MCB of appropriate rating may be safer.

Comment: Manufatureres suggested me that it would work since I am not doing live switching with the relays

Comment: Hi Manjesh, More details of your application will help in arriving at an appropriate solution.

Comment: You could detect the state of the relay by monitoring the voltage on the load